# What is wrong with this regex to be used in JAVA?

Tags: java, regex

What is wrong int the following regex to be used in a JAVA code:

```
    "(\\s[(]((\\w)*(\\s)*)*[)])"
```

This is to replace patterns in a string such as " (foo bar foo bar)".
Thank you.

Comment: I'm sure you've tried something that didn't work, didn't you? Please share that with us, and we'll help you fix it: that's pretty basic stuff.

Comment: I've entered what I've tried.

Comment: And...what happened when you tried it?

Comment: nothing got replaced in a string such as "foo bar foo bar (http foo bar foo) foo bar".

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? The `foo`? The `bar`? Anything in parentheses? What you have is much more complicated than you need.

Comment: You really need to give more detail on this. What are you trying to replace specifically? Are you trying to replace any number of words within parens?

Comment: you said "replaced". how are you using this regex?

Comment: @DavidB anything in parenthesis.

Comment: `"Boy, am I ever glad I can use (lots of (parentheses) in any way that I want!) I don't even (need( to match them!)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the best way to test regex is with a [Regex Tester](http://www.regextester.com/)

Second, it's helpful to get a copy of a [Regex Cheat Sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/)

As regards your problem, because parentheses are a reserved character in Regex, you need to escape these characters using `\`, but in Java, because `\` is a special character, you have to escape it twice - e.g.

```
\\(.*\\)
```

This will match anything between two parentheses.

To limit it to just match word characters and spaces you could use:

```
\\((?:[\\w]|[\\s])*\\)
```

To explain what's going on here:

- `(.)*` instructs to match any number of characters that match the regex in the parantheses
- `(?:.)*` since parantheses means we're grouping, we add `?:` to say we're not interested in the content of the group
- `[\\w]|[\\s]` instructs to match either word characters or white space characters

Comment: `\([\w\s]*\)` This is a smaller version of the second regex you have, and it works with his string.